# NLLLoss is just a normal negative function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I'm having trouble understanding `nn.NLLLoss()`.

Since the code below always prints `True` then what's the difference between the `nn.NLLLoss()` and using the negative sign (-)?

```
import torch
while 1:
   b = torch.randn(1)
   print(torch.nn.NLLLoss()(b, torch.tensor([0])) == -b[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you only have a single output value per batch element and the target is `0`. The [`nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) loss will pick the value of the predicted tensor corresponding to the index contained in the target tensor. Here is a more general example where you have a total of five batch elements each having three logit values:

```
>>> logits = torch.randn(5, 3, requires_grad=True)
>>> y = torch.tensor([1, 0, 2, 0, 1])
>>> y_hat = torch.softmax(b, -1)
```

Tensors `y` and `y_hat` correspond to the target tensor and estimated distributions respectively. You can implement `nn.NLLLoss` with the following:

```
>>> -y_hat[torch.arange(len(y_hat)), y]
tensor([-0.2195, -0.1015, -0.3699, -0.5203, -0.1171], grad_fn=<NegBackward>)
```

Compared to the built-in function:

```
>>> F.nll_loss(y_hat, y, reduction='none')
tensor([-0.2195, -0.1015, -0.3699, -0.5203, -0.1171], grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

Which is quite different to `-y_hat` alone.